# Is there a meta-analysis of this concept anywhere?

Tags: computer-architecture

In a textbook on systems and networks, it states "Stated broadly, a program tends to access a relatively small region of memory irrespective of its actual memory footprint in any given interval of time"

Was there some kind of meta-analysis done on multiple programs to come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

This principle is called **cache locality,** **the locality principle,** or [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).
Not all programs exhibit good locality, in fact there are plenty of real-world programs which don't. For example, any large-enough hash table eventually fails to exhibit locality:

```
ngramcounter = HashTable<(String, String, String), int>
for adjacent words w1, w2, w3 in VeryLargeDocument:
    ngramcounter[(w1, w2, w3)] += 1
```

However, it has been known empirically since very early in the history of computer architecture this property often holds, and *often* is all we need for it to be worth it. An overview-style reference is Denning, *The Locality Principle.* [PDF](http://denninginstitute.com/pjd/PUBS/CACMcols/cacmJul05.pdf) --- discusses the history of how locality became to be recognized by mainstream architectures, including some examples of meta-analyses. An excerpt:

> 1980: Denning gathers the results of over 200 virtual memory researchers and concludes that working set memory management with a single system
> wide window size is as close to optimal as can practically be realized.

I wasn't able to find a paper specifically focusing on a meta-analysis of cache locality in a bunch of studies, but most papers on the topic empirically validate their ideas on real-world programs and the principle is very well established. Just as one example of a possible paper to read with a lot of experimental detail, see Grunwald, Zorn, Henderson, [Improving the Cache Locality of Memory Allocation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/155090.155107?casa_token=8f2su2P5AjIAAAAA:V6Q_YDM7Aa7lnFl4oA-aJ9bpdI8WKcKPa6RSMyoKJ91hlDkF80x-Hmm0XojKNCs-Rw4Bg6zswSZx). There are many others.